# Upload images to Azure blob from front end (React)

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-blob-storage

The front end enables people to upload their photos, so i was sending the base64 to the server and working with it initially, but there are problems with firewall which blocks the request which contains base64. As an alternative solution I was trying to upload the image to azure blob get the file name and then send that to the server for processing where I generate a sas token for the blob validation and processing.

This works perfectly fine when I work locally and the front end connection works with @azure/storage-blob
and uploadBrowserData() when I send the arrayBuffer as the param

```
export const uploadSelfieToBlob = async arrayBuffer => {
    try {
        const blobURL = `https://${accountName}.blob.core.windows.net${sasString}`;
        const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(blobURL, anonymousCredential);
        const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
        let randomString = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
        const blobName = `${randomString}_${new Date().getTime()}.jpg`;
        const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);
        const uploadBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.uploadBrowserData(arrayBuffer);
        return { blobName, blobId: uploadBlobResponse.requestId };
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error when uploading to blob', error);
        throw new Error('Error Uploading the selfie to blob');
    }
};
```

When I deploy this is not working, the front is deployed in the EastUs2 location and the local development location is different.

I thought the sasString generated for anonymous access had the timezone option so I generated 2 different one's one for local and one for hosted server with the same location selected.

```
 Failed to send request to https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/contanainer-name/26pcie_1582087489288.jpg?sv=2019-02-02&ss=b&srt=c&sp=rwdlac&se=2023-09-11T07:57:29Z&st=2020-02-18T00:57:29Z&spr=https&sig=9IWhXo5i%2B951%2F8%2BTDqIY5MRXbumQasOnY4%2Bju%2BqF3gw%3D
```

What am I missing any lead would be helpful thanks

Comment: I’m wondering if you’ve configured CORS rules properly. That could be one reason why your requests are failing once the code is deployed. Other reason could be improperly configured firewall rules.

Comment: @GauravMantri, thanks the error was with the CORS, I was deceived by the trailing slash in the URL. https://xxxx.com/ was changed to https://xxxx.com. and the request was through !

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthorizationResourceTypeMismatch</Code><Message>This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this resource type.
RequestId:7ec96c83-101e-0001-4ef1-e63864000000
Time:2020-02-19T06:57:31.2867563Z</Message></Error>`

This is my error now

Comment: I’ve seen this error coming because of firewall configuration or you’re trying to access the storage over http instead of https.

Comment: @GauravMantri no the request is from https, and the settings in firewall is set to all networks. is that the problem ?

Comment: I think I found the problem. Let me post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, as mentioned in the comments there was an issue with the CORS Settings because of which you're getting the initial error.

> `AuthorizationResourceTypeMismatch`This
>   request is not authorized to perform this operation using this
>   resource type. RequestId:7ec96c83-101e-0001-4ef1-e63864000000
>   Time:2020-02-19T06:57:31.2867563Z

I looked up this error code [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/sas-error-codes) and then closely looked at your SAS URL.

One thing I noticed in your SAS URL is that you have set the `signed resource type (srt)` as `c (container)` and trying to upload the blob. If you look at the description of the kind of operations you can do using `srt=c` [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-account-sas#constructing-the-account-sas-uri), you will notice that blob related operations are not supported.

In order to perform blob related operations (like blob upload), you would need to set signed resource type value to `o (for object)`.

Please regenerate your SAS Token and include signed resource type as object (you can also include container and/or service in there as well) and then your request should work. So essentially your `srt` in your SAS URL should be something like `srt=o` or `srt=co` or `srt=sco`.

Comment: Once I generated a new SAS URL with object, container and service enabled. Things are working now. Thanks a ton. This is my latest SAS for future reference

`?sv=2019-02-02&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&se=2024-02-19T05:00:00Z&st=2020-02-19T06:00:00Z&spr=https&sig=hDLtu6670X31Ivl7L3nXvvEuuTDb5j3HQk3RCiy7Q9s%3D`

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't notice anything wrong with the code you mentioned about, but I have been using a different method to upload files to Azure Blog Storage using React, the method is exactly the same as in this blog article which works perfectly for me. 
https://medium.com/@stuarttottle/upload-to-azure-blob-storage-with-react-34f37805fdfc